# Get text from the page using find_element_by_xpath convert to selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to get the text *"Cleaning General: Audit Based Update"* in the HTML below. It should have the xpath:

```
//*[@id="context_bar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div
```

How do I convert the following Python ElementTree code to Selenium?

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="context_bar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/@title').text()
```

with the following HTML:

[image]

Comment: 1) We can't reproduce this because we don't have the HTML. Please post the URL. 2) What error/issue do you get? When you try debugging your XPATH by successively adding parts to it, where does it stop working?

Comment: hi, 1) Internal site 2) I Just want to print text.

Comment: 1) Ok but we can't reproduce it. 2) Doesn't matter. To debug the xpath, the only sane method I know is start with just `'//*[@id="context_bar"]/table/tbody`, check it works, then add xpath components one-at-a-time until you find where the problem is. Tell us where that is. If you don't debug it and describe the problem better, then we can't help you.

Comment: hi,this code can you convert to selenium   ```title = html.etree.HTML(content).xpath('//*[@id="context_bar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/@title')[0]```

Comment: Oh, you're asking us to convert Python ElementTree code to Selenium. I don't know Selenium but it should be easy, see the Selenium doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're calling is `find_element_by_xpath` so it will return an element.
if you want to get an attribute of an element then you'll need to call `elem.get_attribute(...)`

```
div = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="context_bar"]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div')
title = div.get_attribute('title')
```